# Android ¿Conviene usar un doInBackground dentro de un AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, alertdialog

Buenas a todos. Tengo esta duda...

El caso es que necesito que al hacer click en un item de una lista se 'ejecute' una `URL` que devuelve una respuesta true o false, para confirmar o cancelar una reserva. Estoy usando un `AlertDialog` dentro de un `OnItemClickListener` para aceptar o cancelar la confirmación de la reserva.

Lo que estaba pensando era usar un `doInBackground` dentro del `AlertDialog`. De alguna manera no es conveniente hacer esto? Hay una alternativa viable que recomienden para este caso?. Espero haber podido expresarme bien. Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Este es mi OnItemClickListener:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(this,
            "Click en posición: " + position + " idt: " + listaTurnosLibres.get(position).get("idt"),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //ALERTDIALOG "¿Confirma sacar turno?".
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TurnosLibres.this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_sacar_turno)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_aceptar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //Aceptar
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancelar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //Cancelar
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

EDIT:

### Lo resolví haciendo lo siguiente, puse el `AsyncTask` dentro del `OnItemClickListener` y en el `AlertDialog` si confirma ejecuto la clase SacarTurno(AsyncTask) y si no, no hace nada. Quedó perfecto.

Comment: te sugiero agregues tu código para clarificar tu pregunta. Usar doInBackground () no se puede usar solo sin implementar AsyncTask.

Comment: @Jorgesys Ok, he agregado una parte del código, el OnItemClickListener.

Comment: Lo que comentas es bueno realizar la tarea si el usuario desea confirmar, si no desea simplemente cancela. Lo que comentabas acerca de "dentro de un AlertDialog", en realidad no es dentro, es que el AlertDialog manda la ejecucion del Task o simplemente no realiza nada mediante el boton cancel.

Comment: Claro, creo que me expresé mal al formular la pregunta y realmente no era dentro del AlertDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) en este caso se usaría para que al dar click (dentro de un `OnItemClickListener`) a un elemento del listado, se pueda realizar la tarea de realizar una petición a la url y obtener un resultado, esto sin bloquear el hilo principal.

Al obtener un resultado el [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)  mediante su método `onPostExecute()`, puede realizar, dependiendo del resultado la creación del Dialogo:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     ...
     muestraDialogo();
     ...
 }
```

> ¿Conviene usar un doInBackground dentro de un AlertDialog?

Esto es incorrecto, se puede realizar, pero la finalidad de `onPostExecute()` es poder mostrar en la UI una respuesta en base a el resultado de la tarea.

Lo correcto es mostrar tu `AlertDialog` al realizar la petición obtener un resultado en `onPostExecute()` y en base a eso decidir mostrar o no el `AlertDialog` para confirmar o cancelar una reserva.

Comment: Gracias por responder. No lo había pensando de esa forma, parece ser mucho más lógico y eficiente. Lo voy a intentar. Te quería comentar que a su vez estoy usando un asynctask para llenar la lista, no creo que sea problema, verdad?

Comment: Al contrario si usas un AsyncTask para llenar la lista es correcto ya que haces una petición y al final realizas la actualización en la UI, que sería el llenado de.datos en el ListView @luis_snk

Comment: disculpa que te vuelva a molestar. Según tu primer respuesta, al dar click a un elemento del listado ya se ejecutaría la petición a la URL  y obtendría el resultado. Lo que sucede al obtener el resultado es que si es "1" ya habrá confirmado la reserva y si es "0" no se realizaría dicha reserva. Por eso preguntaba, si era conveniente (o si se puede) usar el AsyncTask dentro de un AlertDialog.

Comment: Lo resolví haciendo lo siguiente, puse el AsyncTask dentro del OnItemClickListener y en el AlerDialog si confirma ejecuto la clase SacarTurno(AsyncTask) y si no, no hace nada. Quedó perfecto.
Jorge, la verdad, no sé cómo agradecerte, me has ayudado un montón. Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: @luis_snk "1" ya habrá confirmado la reserva y si es "0" no se realizaría dicha reserva... de hecho aquí si esta confirmado simplemente solo se mostraria un mensaje, si no es asì podrìas mostrar el Dialogo para que confirme o cancele. Saludos!

Comment: @luis_snk excelente Luis, me da gusto, saludos!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63832/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-luis-snk).